# Where can I find some simple code examples of recursion in C++?

Tags: c++, methods, recursion

I am completely newbie to C++. I am doing a practice which consists of building a very simple C++ program.

My teacher emphasizes that it must use recursion with functions and methods. I am wondering how to use recursion within a method in C++. I was looking for some code examples but I haven't find anything. My deep concerns are how a method calls itself without not knowing the name of its class/instance.

Comment: Have you tried asking your favorite search engine for "c++ recursion"?

Comment: "I am doing a practice which consists in building up a very simple C++ compiler" - is this a joke?

Comment: If you implement member functions as free functions with an additional instance pointer, then the recursion just passes the `this` pointer of the current instance to the next call... what exactly are you confused about?

Comment: I must also wonder at the thought process behind "I'm a complete newbie in X" and "I want to do the most difficult thing conceivable pertaining to X". What's going on?

Comment: I found lots of examples with recursion, but any done with the methods, only with functions.

It's not a joke. It is simple because it hasn't use heap.

I'm a newbie in C++, but the teacher gave us a sub-set of the current C++ language (no STL for instance). But for this type of questions the specification is not clear.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int offset) : offset(offset) {}

    int bar(int x)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            return offset;  // Base-case
        }
        return x + bar(x-1);  // Recursion
    }

private:
    int offset;
};


int main()
{
    Foo foo(7);
    std::cout << foo.bar(5) << "\n";  Prints "22" (5+4+3+2+1+7)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia: Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)

I guess your homework is to write a [Recursive Descent Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). A simple example in C:
[uBASIC](http://www.sics.se/~adam/ubasic/)

Comment: It is a LL(1) compiler. They even give us the algorithm to do the parsing.

Comment: Question changed to no longer be about compiling

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int factorial(int n)    // 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, ...  
  {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
  }

  main()
  {
    int n = 7;

    cout << "Enter a non-negative integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "The Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial(n) << endl;  

    return 0;
  }
```

You can find more examples here : http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/tutorials/cpp/cpp6.php